# How can I use PHP call python script return result in realtime?

Tags: php, python

I used PHP to call python script successfully and got the result . But I have to wait for the end of script running without anything output. It looks not friendly to my customer.

How can I return the script results to the PHP web in realtime ?

For instance ,for code below , I want to the PHP web will show output message in realtime instead of show them together at the end . How can I change my code?
Thank you .

PHP Code:

```
 <?php
$k = $_REQUEST['k'];
if (!empty($k))
{
$k = trim($k);
$a = array();
exec('python ./some.py '.$k, $a);
echo $a[0];
}
?>
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys

def do_some(a):
    print 'test1'
    time.sleep(30)
    print 'test2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Now the python scritp running'
    time.sleep(20)
    a = sys.argv[1]
    if a:
    print 'Now print something'
    T = do_some(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specification, `exec` stop the calling program until the end of the callee. *After* that, you get back the output in a variable.

If you want to send data as soon as they are produced, you should use [`popen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php). It will fork a new process, but will not block the caller. So you can perform other tasks, like looping to read the sub-process output line by line to send it to your client. Something *like* that:

```
$handle = popen("python ./some.py ", 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
    ob_flush();
}
pclose($handle)
```

Comment: I am sorry that I am too busy to reply for your answer instantly.Yes,your answer is right,and I used your code solve my problem.Thank you again.